# How do I solve the Frenet-Serret equations for the curve, instead the curvature/torsion?

Tags: algorithms, frenet-frame

So I happen to be working in a hobby side project which happens to be increasingly convoluted so now, naturally, I have come to the aid of the gurus.

It turns out that I am trying to solve the Frenet-Serret equations to find the curve, instead of the curvatures and torsions. Let $\bf T$, $\bf N$ and $\bf B$ be the Frenet frame vectors. And let us define the matrix $\bf Q$ to be

$
\bf Q = 
\left [
\begin{array}{c}
\bf T \\
\bf N \\
\bf B
\end{array}
\right ]
$

The Frenet-Serret equations can be defined as:

$
\left (
\frac{d}{ds}
\right )
{\bf Q}
=
{\bf Q}'
=
{\bf F}
\cdot 
{\bf Q}
$

where

$
{\bf F}=
\left [
\begin{array}{}
0 & \kappa & 0 \\
-\kappa & 0 & \tau \\
0 & -\tau & 0
\end{array} 
\right ]
$

I have the curvatures $\kappa(s)$ and torsions $\tau(s)$ for all $s$, they are continuous functions and I wish to find the curve that solves it. To do that, I put up a crude algorithm. I have little experience with solving differential equations in a computer, but I did not find libraries I could use to solve these equations in this fashion. So I kickstarted the Algorithm with some arbitrary starting conditions.

1. ${\bf P}_0 = \bf 0$
2. ${\bf T}_0 = [1,0,0]$
3. ${\bf N}_0 = [0,1,0]$
4. ${\bf B}_0 = {\bf T}_0 \times {\bf N}_0$

And then I started an iterative algorithm with termination conditions being the curve reaching a certain final length $S$. Each iteration increment the total length $S$ by means of small constant increments of $\delta s$. Each cycle goes like this:

5. Assemble
   ${\bf Q}_i = 
   \left [
   \begin{array}{c}
   {\bf T}_i \\
   {\bf N}_i \\
   {\bf B}_i
   \end{array}
   \right ]
   $
6. Find the derivatives by means of ${\bf Q}_i' = {\bf F}(s) {\bf Q}_i$
7. Update the quantities by means of ${\bf Q}_i= {\bf Q}_{i-1} + {\bf Q}_{i-1}'$
8. Update the curve by adding a new point ${\bf P}_i$ such that ${\bf P}_i = {\bf P}_{i-1} + {\bf T}_{i-1}$

This way I could, potentially, use a very small $\Delta s$ to approximate a trajectory which could be a sequence of points created by updating the starting point by means of the step 8 abov for a total length of trajectory. It $seems$ reasonable, but I suspect it might be just ignorance being bliss, because I implemented this in a simpe python algorithm and let it run, and the trajectory quickly explodes in huge coordinates, as if the particle has been going to extremes. Are those crazy coordinates a feature of the particular ${\bf F}$ matrix I am using, or is that ignorance comming up to say hi?

I thank all those who take their time to read this through and patiently correct me. I also thank those not so patient, I just want to know what is going wrong and why.

Thanksabunch!

Comment: First, in (7) one should include a factor of a suitable approximate differential (something involving like $\Delta s$, depending on how you handle the next issue). Second, what parameter value corresponds to the $i$th step, that is, for what value of $s_0$ is ${\bf Q}_i$ supposed to approximate ${\bf Q}(s_0)$?

Comment: Any specific way in which I should use $\Delta s$ in (7)? I'm really clueless, sort of. The algorithm is maybe the best I can do with my current knowledge. You can try and explain $why$ I would need that factor, so that I could fortunately figure out by myself how should I do this. Also, the only dependence ${\bf Q}_i$ has for $s$ is by means of $\kappa(s)$ and $\tau(s)$ which are known continuous functions. The initial vector ${\bf Q}(s_0) = {\bf Q}_0$ is made from the initialization conditions.${\bf Q}_0 = [{\bf T}_0, {\bf N_0}, {\bf B}_0]$

Comment: As for why you need that factor, what happens when you solve an ODE $y'(x) = f(x, y)$ numerically using the analogous method. As for your dependence, which value $s$ do you use in ${\bf F}(s)$ in the $i$th iteration of step 6?

Comment: ${\bf F}(s)$ for step 6 is equal to ${\bf F}(s_0 + 6 \Delta s)$. As I said, $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are continuous functions, defined for all $s$. in this particular case, each of them is $\kappa(s) = \tau(s) = cos(s)+10$.

Comment: (Is $6 \Delta s$ supposed to be $i \Delta s$ here?)

Comment: Aye. The $s$ starts at $s_0 = 0$ and is incremented with the same interval $\Delta s$ throughout all steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24120/discussion-between-urquiza-and-travis).